# Find final price in a dataframe of transactions with reference to a monthly refunds dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe of transactions which contains the product purchased, the date, and the gross price.

```
     Product       Date Price
1        Tea 2020-12-17   1.0
2  Ice-cream 2020-12-17   2.0
3        Tea 2021-01-19   1.0
4      Bread 2021-02-02   0.5
5      Bread 2021-02-02   0.5
6        Tea 2021-03-03   1.0
7        Tea 2021-03-05   1.0
8  Ice-cream 2021-03-05   2.0
9  Ice-cream 2021-03-09   2.0
10     Bread 2021-03-10   0.5

transactions <- data.frame(
    Product = c("Tea", "Ice-cream", "Tea", "Bread", "Bread", "Tea", "Tea", "Ice-cream", "Ice-cream", "Bread"), 
    Date=as.Date(c("17-12-2020", "17-12-2020", "19-01-2021", "02-02-2021", "02-02-2021", "03-03-2021", "05-03-2021", "05-03-2021", "09-03-2021", "10-03-2021"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"), 
    Price = c(1.00, 2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.50, 1.00, 1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 0.50)
)
```

However, under the arrangement some the cost of some products is refunded on a monthly basis, thus there is another dataframe called "refunds"

```
        Month Product Amount
1 December 20     Tea   0.50
2  January 21     Tea   0.50
3 February 21   Bread   0.50
4    March 21     Tea   1.00
5    March 21   Bread   0.25

refund <- data.frame(
  Month = c("December 20", "January 21", "February 21", "March 21", "March 21"),
  Product = c("Tea", "Tea", "Bread", "Tea", "Bread"),
  Amount = c(0.50, 0.50, 0.50, 1.00, 0.25)
)
```

I need to create an additional column in my "transactions" dataframe which reflects the *net price*, i.e. the price minus (the total refund for that month / number of that product purchased that month).

For simplicity I assumed that the refund arrangment is half the price of bread and tea, with no refund for ice-cream, so the answer should look like this.

```
     Product       Date Price Final_Price
1        Tea 2020-12-17   1.0        0.50
2  Ice-cream 2020-12-17   2.0        2.00
3        Tea 2021-01-19   1.0        0.50
4      Bread 2021-02-02   0.5        0.25
5      Bread 2021-02-02   0.5        0.25
6        Tea 2021-03-03   1.0        0.50
7        Tea 2021-03-05   1.0        0.50
8  Ice-cream 2021-03-05   2.0        2.00
9  Ice-cream 2021-03-09   2.0        2.00
10     Bread 2021-03-10   0.5        0.25

netprice_df <- data.frame(
  Product = c("Tea", "Ice-cream", "Tea", "Bread", "Bread", "Tea", "Tea", "Ice-cream", "Ice-cream", "Bread"), 
  Date=as.Date(c("17-12-2020", "17-12-2020", "19-01-2021", "02-02-2021", "02-02-2021", "03-03-2021", "05-03-2021", "05-03-2021", "09-03-2021", "10-03-2021"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"), 
  Price = c(1.00, 2.00, 1.00, 0.50, 0.50, 1.00, 1.00, 2.00, 2.00, 0.50)
  Final_Price = c(0.50, 2.00, 0.50, 0.25, 0.25, 0.50, 0.50, 2.00, 2.00, 0.25)
)
```

The real data is more complex than this.

Managing the date element is where I am having trouble...any help of tip would be much appreciated.

Note* I don't have easy access to the CRAN library, however I have Tidyverse downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the 'Date' column to the `format` in 'refund' data, do a `left_join` and get the 'Final_price'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
transactions%>%
    mutate(Month = format(ymd(Date), '%B %y')) %>%
    left_join(refund) %>%        
    group_by(Product, Month) %>%,
    mutate(Amount = -Amount/n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(Final_price = rowSums(select(., Price, Amount), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    select(names(transactions), Final_price)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Product   Date       Price Final_price
#   <chr>     <date>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 Tea       2020-12-17   1          0.5 
# 2 Ice-cream 2020-12-17   2          2   
# 3 Tea       2021-01-19   1          0.5 
# 4 Bread     2021-02-02   0.5        0.25
# 5 Bread     2021-02-02   0.5        0.25
# 6 Tea       2021-03-03   1          0.5 
# 7 Tea       2021-03-05   1          0.5 
# 8 Ice-cream 2021-03-05   2          2   
# 9 Ice-cream 2021-03-09   2          2   
#10 Bread     2021-03-10   0.5        0.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't have lubridate on my main laptop, but when I run the example on by personal laptop it returns a different answer - i.e. the final price is higher than the price, whereas I should be taking the refund amount off.

Comment: @Sean I changed the sign of the 'Amount' column to `-` and then used `rowSums`

Comment: Still seems to be adding rather than subtracting, but a bigger issue is when multiples of the same product are purchased in the same month (i.e. tea in March 2020) the code takes off the full refund, rather than the full refund divided by the number purchased that month.

Comment: @Sean do you want to subtract or divide

Comment: @Sean i updatd the post

Comment: I need to divide the refund amount my the number of the product bought in a given month, and subtract that from each line. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sean I updated the post bassed on that logic

Comment: Returning: Error in mutate(Amount = -Amount/n()) : object 'Amount' not found

Comment: Thanks Akrun, that looks perfect. Is is prob an update issue on my end.

Comment: It seems to have just been an issue with copy/pasting the characters into the console. Thanks so much Akrun, have a great day :)